# List<> cannot be used C#

Tags: c#, list

I have this error and I don't have any idea what's happening, I'm new learning C# and where I'm learning they use this:

```
using System;

namespace AgentSmith
{
    class AgentSmith_missions
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double[] array = {1.1, 2.2, 3.3};
            List<double> times  = new List<double>();
            times.Add(4.20);
            times.Add(7.30);
            times.Insert(1, 9.35);
            var four = times.IndexOf(4.20);
            times.Remove(times[four]);
            double seven = times.Contains(7.30);
            string s = String.Join(", ", times);
            Console.WriteLine(s + seven);
       }
    }
}
```

The console error is this:

```
/Users.../AgentSmith.cs(10,13): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'List<>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    
/Users.../AgentSmith.cs(10,39): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'List<>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Comment: `using System.Collections.Generic;`

Comment: Then the same error occurs in String, Console and .Contains

Comment: @GonzaloCecilianodelaPeña you'll need `using System;` **and** `using System.Collections.Generic;`

Comment: In VS the solution is to press CTRL+<dot> on List in source code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a keyboard shortcut that'll make this easier to fix:

`Control .`

That is, the `Control` key plus the period `.` key.

That keyboard shortcut tries to resolve the item under the cursor, which often is a matter of adding a using to bring a namespace into scope.  If you get an error squiggly on something that you know is defined, click on it and hit `Control .` and look for the missing namespace.

Answer (score 0):

you want to add this `using` at the top of your class:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have coded for a list in your `Main` function. But you also need to add a reference to the `List` class so that your compiler knows what to do with `List`. Just add the following to the top of your file:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

In addition, it looks like this line could cause a problem as well:

```
double seven = times.Contains(7.30);
```

`Contains` returns a `bool`. It's `true` or `false` based on whether or not the list contains that value. What you are probably looking for here is `First`, which returns the first value that matches:

```
double seven = times.First(x => x == 7.30);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add System.Collections.Generic; add also times.Contains(7.30); return a booleen not a double.